# Rails postresql installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

*Hi folks, I have a problem when I try to install the postgresql, it is about a project, first I install the postgresql, then I write: sudo bundle install and it gives me this error and I cannot run the project because of it:*

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.20.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out
```

*Below is the code from the file: mkmf.log*

```
nd_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1547: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.3  -Wl,-rpath, -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.3.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Please include the logfile. This is a bit too vague to give any help on.

Comment: OK, I will add the code now from the mkmf.log

Comment: I did it, the thing I needed to do is:

Comment: I think, if you install this package libpq-dev, it helps. You can install it like: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev. For further information, you can check out this website as well: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04.